# What is best practice when it comes to "feature blocking" in react?

Tags: reactjs, security

For our React application, we have a number of features that should only be available to users who have the correct subscription level.

The application requires the user to log in. It's at that point the application will become aware of the users settings, including what features of the application they can/cannot use.

What would be the best approach for preventing someone hacking their account using a simple JS debugger to change their settings?

We're very early days in the app development so there isn't much code to show. We're looking for best practices and advice.

Thanks for any help

EDIT:
I suppose the main point of the question is how does one prevent a user from adjusting the code to show a module that might not be available to the user. At some point, there will be logic that decides if a component is shown or not...

```
if (user.hasModuleA)
    return new moduleA;
```

... what would stop someone from changing the code at run time to...

```
if (true)
    return new moduleA;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the concerns; authentication `!=` authorization.

Rather than sending the permissions back in a plain object from an API (which is how I'm guessing you're doing that), it is better to send granular access control and permissions back inside of an encrypted, trusted token; something like JSON Web Tokens would work well for that.

The token is generated by your authentication logic and returned along with other information about the current user. Since it is hashed using your secret, any changes that are made to the token on the client side will produce a different token entirely whose signature produces a mismatch.

Further reading:

- [When should you use JSON Web Tokens?](https://jwt.io/introduction)
- [Using JWT (JSON Web Tokens) to authorize users and protect API routes](https://medium.com/@maison.moa/using-jwt-json-web-tokens-to-authorize-users-and-protect-api-routes-3e04a1453c3e)

Comment: Hi @BenM, Thanks for you reply. Our approach will be to use a JWT so I'm happy we're on the same wavelength there. How would one prevent someone changing the logic? I've added an example to the question

Comment: You really can't prevent against that sort of attack. You should instead validate requests with the server instead.